# Url that downloads file in android

Tags: java, android, url

I have a url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGhQTs3F1O4&spf=prefetch that when I open in the browser it downloads a file containing the info of the video..

that works well in the browser but I can't implement that in Android.. when I try to download the file using the following code I get the html file..

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/" + sUrl[1];
        Log.d(TAG, "PATH: " + path);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP "
                        + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                        + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

So.. Any idea ?

Comment: Try to set the MIME type in the request.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT without usage of deprecated class:

It seems that they check the user agent, therefore you'll have to set it like this:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
connection.connect();
```

OLD ANSWER:
For me it works with the usage of HTTPClient instead of HTTPConnection (and, in my opinion, for this case, there is no reason to use the latter class)

Here's an example:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(sUrl[0]);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);
        return EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

    } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
    }
}
```

You should also consider the usage of [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: Actually both classes have been deprecated. Use UrlConnection instead. Check this [reference](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Comment: @OP it my answer helped you can you check it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
    class A extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
        @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 Log.e("ASYNCTASK", "DONE");
              }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGhQTs3F1O4&spf=prefetch";
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse=  client.execute(httpGet);
            if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                //long fileLength = httpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength();
            InputStream input = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
              FileOutputStream  output = new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/yahoo.json");
              byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }

                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```